# Assert a class method

Tags: python, class, assert

I use `assert` to check newly written functions. An example:

```
def assertOutside(test):
        return test == True
assert assertOutside(True) == True
```

Now I would like to do the same testing within classes: check the method:

```
class Klasse:
    def assertInside(self,test):
        return test == True
    assert assertInside(True) == True
```

but here one gets the error: `TypeError:  missing 1 required positional argument.`

What is the correct way to write an `assert` inside a class to do a manatory test on a method?

Comment: You've created an instance method, so you would have to create an instance to do this in a way that is useful.

Comment: In this case `assertInside(None, "...")` would work because it doesn't use any instance state, but then the question becomes: why is it an instance method? Also: why are you doing these assertions? If you want to write *tests* there are many better ways to do that (in the standard library alone there's both [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) and [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html), for example).

Comment: You saved my day, thank you.
The reason for doing it this way is regulatory. This way I can prove  quickly to the auditor that something works, and that it is validated.
I agree it is not very Pythonian, but it serves the purpose.

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger it doesn't prove anything - unless you have a whole slew of assertions - and what do you do when your test cases neede fully constructted instances, or even instances of of data that you don't want to access during testing (i.e. the sort of thing that mock is there for). I would suggest that your assertions don't prove much of anything - they are a poor man's unit test - they look like they prove compliance, but prove only that some simple tests work.
Any auditor would want to see a full set of test cases with fxtures, stubs for external interfaces etc etc.

Comment: @Tony. Yes I do have a whole slew of assertions. For simplicity, I just reduced the question to the core. My auditors are in the medical field and are comming to me to learn about software validation. I know well, that "assert" is not a fool-proof method, but sufficently good in some applications.

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger - if your test cases are trivial then they are just about sufficient - but what would you do if one of your message raises an exception (for example), or needs a number of data items established before calling the method ... the assert can only do so much. I think you should be looking to train your auditors in pytest, or unittest or nose or similar ...

Comment: @Tony, I am with you. My auditors do not have a programming background, they are working with the government or at notified bodies: in their earlier live they had a marketing background or dental technican background (no joke!!!). Monday I get a new audit, I will try your suggestions, lets see how they react...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with the solution of **jonrsharpe**:

```py
class Klasse:
    def assertInside(self,test):
        return test == True
    assert assertInside(None,True) == True
```